# Is it Possible to Create like Elementer App (Wordpress) in React js?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am trying to create like elementer app (Wordpress) in react using react dnd (npm) , there is lot of problems came when creating Html Elements , any one can suggest for creating way or any packages to to this app .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague.

But I'll give you a bit of a starting point.
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-create-block/ explains how to create a block in a plugin.

Then have a look at the entirety of this: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/ - and you might kind of know where to start.

In general you can use react components anywhere with gutenberg. However mostly in the backend. Using them in the front end does often not make that much sense - then you are better off working with wordpress as a headless CM (via RestAPI).

Hope this helped you.

Comment: Thanks ,  my app is nothing but  just drag and drop the elements  and working area and give the value and css properties and saved it

https://elementor.com/  -> like this

Comment: You have to add either a very detailed explanation, or some code you have already written.
Noone can help you like this.